# Play Store updates downloaded on 3G network by ignoring settings

Tags: google-play-store, sony-xperia-j

On my Xperia J phone Google Play Store setting of automatic updates is set to: Wi-fi only.

To my greatest surprise, yesterday it started to download 50MBs of updates when I was on 3G and my 200MB package was almost exceeded.

I checked the Data usage of Google Play Store on my 3G network and on Wifi: Wifi has 432 MB traffic, **3G has 82 MB** (with wifi-only settings).

My question is: what settings should I use to prevent the abuse of my 3G package? Have you experienced similar behavior?

Comment: Is your phone rooted ?

Comment: No, it is not. It has low internal storage (about 70 MB), but it is not rooted.

Comment: Exact same symptoms here, also using a Sony Xperia phone, Android 4.1.2. And it is using far and away more 3G bandwidth than anything else on this handset. ...Just found the same behaviour on my Android 4.2.2 cheap Chinese phone.
We will try switching off google play updates completely, and see if it stops it. (If I forget to report back, please ask!)

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done so already, try going to `Settings - Data usage`, then press the menu key and choose "Restrict background data".

This sets all sync functions to only work on Wi-Fi, maybe it also helps with your Play Store problem. Be careful though, if you rely on sync to work even when you are not on Wi-Fi (Gmail for example), this is not the right option for you.

Comment: You're missing the final step, keen: what you write just establishes a general data limit. After enabling that, one has to scroll the list of apps below it, and deactivate (turn-off) background data usage for the app in question explicitly. Other apps are only affected then when the set limit is reached. But yes, that's the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of [No Root Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall) if you want only some apps to access the Internet from your phone if your device is not rooted. If your device is rooted you can use [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall)