# Why do Google Play Services appear to access Location despite being disallowed to?

Tags: permissions, google-play-services, geolocation

On my phone I disallowed *Google Play Services* access to *Location* many months ago. Yet *Recent Location Requests* item of the Settings still gets them listed:

[image]

How can this happen? Do *Google Play Services* have some special privilege to work around permission checking? Or are the apps that get denied permission to access *Location* still registered in this list?

Comment: Google Services are part of the system – so yes, they tend to ignore the user's preferences (also [see here](/q/196248/16575#comment-271456)). Not only that: I once disabled Play Store on a device – and guess what: it re-activated itself again, pulling updates while I was on mobile data, burning 1/3 of my monthly data plan within half an hour. Luckily, my current devices are Google-free.

Comment: Play Services is the location provider i.e. other apps rely on it for high accuracy location services (other than GPS). You cannot deny location permission to a location provider. All Google apps are privileged: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218153/218526. Explore your `/etc/permissions/` and `/etc/sysconfig/` directories to know the details.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225549